# Delta of numbers in file

Tags: text-processing, numbering

On our server a cronjob has logged a count of files in a shared directory. The log is of the form:

```
2003-07-03T16:05 279
2003-07-03T16:10 283
2003-07-03T16:15 282
```

By now this file has far over a million entries. I am interested in finding the biggest changes we ever had (negative and positive). I can write a program to find this, but is there some tool that can give me a list of deltas?

The original is on Solaris, but I have a copy of the file on my Linux Mint system.

Comment: you can get the values using awk $2 then I believe you can do some basic shell math ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the package [`num-utils`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) installed, you can do:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2 inputfile | numinterval | sort -u
```

The first and the last number there give the min, resp. max changes.

If that list is too long and you also have [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) installed you can do:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2 inputfile | numinterval | sort -u | pee "tail -1" "head -1"
```

On Mint you should be able to install those packages, on Solaris you probably have to compile from source.

Comment: +1. Despite the [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) :P.

Comment: @terdon +2 now?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{last=0}{delta[NR]=$2-last; last=$2; print $0" "delta[NR]}' file
```

will give you

```
2003-07-03T16:05 279 279
2003-07-03T16:10 283 4
2003-07-03T16:15 282 -1
```

with deltas in last column, so to find the biggest just pipe it to sort

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{last=0}{delta[NR]=$2-last; last=$2; print $0" "delta[NR]}' file | sort -k3n
2003-07-03T16:15 282 -1
2003-07-03T16:10 283 4
2003-07-03T16:05 279 279
```

but for million entries this will be really slow. I would probably use `mysql` or other db instead.

Comment: +1. You could also just calculate the greatest in the awk directly: `awk -v last=0 '{k=($2-last);if(NR==2){max=k}if(k > max){max=k} last=$2}END{print max}' file`

Comment: @terdon true, but I guess that OP wants not only a number but the whole line which corresponds to this number. One thing is for sure - I unnecessary used array instead of plain variable as in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Shows two lines with the biggest difference between

```
awk '{c=$2-a[2];
      if(c<0)c=-c;
      if(+a[2]&&c>b){b=c;d=a[1]" "a[2]"\n"$0};
      split($0,a," ")}
  END{print "Difference is",b,"between:\n"d}'
```